# How do I get this stepper button div to sit at the bottom of the page?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

so i feel like an idiot. i can't quite figure this out. any help would absolutely be appreciated.

structure...

```
base layout: 
<> 
    <Header />
    <div className="flex h-screen overflow-hidden">
        <Sidebar />
        <main className="w-full pt-16">
            {children}
        </main>
    </div> 
</> 

child layout: 
<> 
    <div className="h-full overflow-auto"> 
        <div className="h-full flex-1 space-y-4 p-4 md:p-8 pt-6"> 
            {children} 
        </div> 
    </div> 
</> 
child component layout: 
<> 
        <div className="flex items-center justify-between"> 
            ...header component
        </div>
        <div>
            ...stepper progress bar
        </div>
        <Form>
            ...form
        </Form>
        <div className="mt-8 py-6"> 
            <div className="flex justify-between self-end"> 
                ...stepper buttons... 
            </div> 
        </div>
    </Form>
</>
```

issue is i need those buttons to sit on the bottom of the viewport, but if the page extends and overflow-auto is triggered, the buttons should still sit at the bottom of the viewport. i can't take the buttons out of this component and set it as a footer because the functions are tied to the form inside the child component layout.

any help would be super appreciated.

i tried giving the parent container (div mt-8 py-6) of the button container full height but it just caused some weight height issues extending into overflow when there shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is to fix some buttons to the bottom of the viewport, then you will have to use fixed positioning. Apply `position:fixed; bottom: 0` style

More on fixed positioning [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#fixed_positioning)

Comment: that's not quite what i'm looking for, because then it may overlap some of the form elements when it overflows

Comment: Can you please share a jsfiddle of the current state and then state your problem ?